# NuGet.exe not packing directories that start with dot

Tags: nuget

I am using NuGet.exe to pack up a directory of files and it seems that it ignores any directory that starts with a dot. Even when I try to explicitly use the "files" entry in the nuspec file, it won't let me include that directory or any of the files within it.

Is there a way to override this behavior?

Here is my command line:
NuGet.exe pack ..\build\MyPackage.nuspec -OutputDirectory "\someserver\blah" -basePath "c:\temp\packageStaging" -Version "3.0" -NoPackageAnalysis

The reason for NoPackageAnalysis is that I am making a non standard package for use in Octopus deploy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you could use -NoDefaultExcludes option of nuget.exe

more details here: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/command-line-reference
NoDefaultExcludes Prevent default exclusion of NuGet package files and files and folders starting with a dot e.g. .svn.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old thread, but I had same problem today, the directory ".well-known" was not added to the nupkg-file.

I solved it by removing the "dot" in the directory name to and added a "target" in the nuspec file:

```
<file src="well-known\**" target="./.well-known/"/>
```